# Equivalent tool to Modo tack tool?

Tags: modeling

is there any tool in blender that is similar to the tack tool in Modo?

here is a video of the tool in action:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aeRkIkQl1c

it use snap to mesh surface + duplicate

Thank you!

Comment: What part of the video do you want to repeat? It is possible to snap and duplicate via shrinkwrapped mesh+duplifaces, but they would be disconnected from active geometry.

Comment: just a quick way to position objects on the mesh, even without deforming them.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't make your question depend on people watching a video. While videos are helpful, they should be supplemental to the text, you should thoroughly explain through words what the tool does.

Answer (score 1):

**Shrinkwrap modifer + Duplifaces**

Green cone is instanced while snapped to Suzanne's geometry:

[image]

1. Add a Plane, scale it down in *Edit mode* to something like 0.01
2. Add *Shrinkwrap* modifier to the *Plane*, switch to *Project* mode, enable both directions to shrink, set *Target* mesh and enable *Adjust edit cage* (all icons near modifier's name)
3. Add object to be duplicated, parent it to the *Plane*
4. In *Plane*'s object settings enable *Duplifaces*

Now in *Edit mode* you can start copying *Plane* (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>), move copies and in realtime see result of their placement. If direction of Dupli gone wrong then flip normal of a plane (Edit Mode->W->Flip Normals)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that's what I was looking for.